# Validating the age limit using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to check whether the entered age is between the specific limit, using Jquery in html forms

Answer (score 3):

Use the jquery validate library http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/ you can take a look there

```
  $("#myform").validate({
   rules: {
   field: {
   required: true,
   rangelength: [2, 6]
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$('input#age').change(function() {
    var age = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if(age < 18 || age > 65) {
        alert("Wrong age!");
    }
});
```

Adjust as necessary.

Comment: the above function should be inside the ("selector").validate() method, right?